# Operating speed of processing planar images vs interleaved images

Tags: objective-c, c, image, image-processing

I am reading a book on advanced iOS programming which says "It's generally much faster to work on planar formats than interleaved formats. If at all possible, get your data into planar format as soon as you can , and leave it in the at format through the entire transformation process".

I got to wondering why that is. The only reason I could come up with was that as you are iterating over your pixels, that you can use ++ operator instead of things like w*y+x to calculate your offsets.

I am familiar with planar vs interleaved as well as RGBA vs YUV. I've written a lot of c code to do things like image format conversion, rotations, flips, resizing, etc... The conversions were typically either to or from i420.

Is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: This might require a little bit of the context from the book in which that was written, but it may have to do with the native formats that iOS works with in AV Foundation and elsewhere. Generally, you get frames from the iOS camera natively in YUV420p, and AV Foundation seems optimized around handling YUV planar data. Also, if you wish to upload this to OpenGL ES, it's easier to work with separate textures for the Y and UV planes than to have them be interlaced. BGRA can also be uploaded to OpenGL ES fairly quickly, though.

Answer (score 0):

Sweeping generalizations like the one you quote are often of limited practical applicability (i.e. almost, but not quite, entirely generalized from one or two data points ;-)

You say you have written a lot of C code for image processing. Good, take it to the next step: learn how to use a profiler, write microbenchmarks to unit-test the performance of your algorithms, especially when you are exploring the solution space.